# How to select json item un handlebar

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js

How can I select an element in a json array in Handlebarjs
I tried navigating the each but the position of the element in the array.
[Json array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRtrj.png)

Comment: Please post your code in text and not in an image.

Answer (score 0):

`#each` takes an array to iterate over, so passing it `media.thumbnails[1]` won't work, as that is the second object in the array. Try passing it the array `media.thumbnails`

Comment: When I use media.thumbnails it shows me all the images that come in the array and I just need to select the second image. that's why I was trying to use media.thumbnails.[1]

Comment: Ok, then you don't need to use `#each`. Use `<img src="{{ media.thumbnail[1].url }}"/>`  instead without the `#each`.

Comment: Thank you very much, the correct use was <img src = "{{media.thumbnails.[1] .url}}" />

Answer (score 0):

i hope to solve your problem, otherwise pass me the complete code

```
<div id="handlebarsDetail"> </div> 

<script id="handleMarkup" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each media.thumbnails}}
     <figure>
     <img src="{{url}}" />
     </figure>
    {{/each}}
</script>

var sourceHandlebars = $("#handleMarkup").html();
var templateHandlebars = Handlebars.compile(sourceHandlebars);

$.getJSON("urlFileJson", function (data) {
     var $htmlHandlebars = jQuery(templateHandlebars(data));
     $("#handlebarsDetail").empty().append($htmlHandlebars); 
});
```